# gnome-shell | extensions | crash

Tags: intel, gnome-shell-extension

Tablet: Dell Venue-11-Pro-7130-vPro
Kernel: Linux version 5.8.0-43
BIOS: A28
RAM: 3840 MB

After installing gnome-shell and overloading the device, I get `/var/crash/` logs with error reports. Of the entire packages extensions, that comes to me by air, I can use only these packages without errors.

[image]

```
Block Caribou 36
Desktop Icons
Horizontal workspaces
Ubuntu AppIndicators
Ubuntu Dock
User Themes
Window List
Workspace Indicator
```

Comment: please provide more information about the crashes and error reports ...

Comment: But in order to provide error reports, I need to flash it again, I just recently cleared it of all these buggy packages. I wouldn't want to go through that again. See it in the emulator to see how it works on my device.

Comment: you need to provide more information, how the crash is happening ? does your desktop freeze ? you mentioned that you get a lot of logs in /var/crash then this is the place to search for the crashes

Comment: I enter the command sudo apt install gnome gnome-shell, then I restart the device and the fan turns long and loud, after I pass along the path to the folder /var/crash/ I see 4-5 huge reports. I made rm /var/crash/* and I began to get rid of packages by the method of exclusion.